# Set data to elements in jsrender

Tags: jquery-templates, jsrender, jsviews

I try to set the data to the elements in jsrender.

Eg: `{{setdata:id 'hai' 'hello'}}`

```
jQuery.views.converters({
          setdata: function(id){
              var key = this.tagCtx.args[1];
              var value = this.tagCtx.args[2];

              jQuery("#" + id).data(key, value);
              return "";
          },
});
```

Is there any way to set the data easily instead of directly in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example would not work because JsRender render method converts from data to a string (HTML markup) which you **then** insert into the DOM (http://www.jsviews.com/#rendertmpl). So when the converter is called, the element you are targeting has not yet been instantiated.

So to set data you have to use the HTML markup `data-xxx="..."` so it gets set on the element when you insert it into the DOM.

Here are some variants. You can write:

```
<div id="a" data-foo="bar"></div>
<div id="b" data-{{:key}}="{{:value}}"></div>
<div id="c" {{setdata:'hai' 'hello'}}></div>
<div id="d" {{setdata:key value}}></div>
```

with

```
jQuery.views.converters({
  setdata: function(key, value){
    return "data-" + key + "='" + value + "'";
  }
});
```

and get

```
console.log($("#a").data('foo')
  + " " + $("#b").data('hai')
  + " " + $("#c").data('hai')
  + " " + $("#d").data('hai')); // bar hello hello hello
```

**Passing and object to an HTML element: use JsViews:**

If you want to pass in an object as data, not a string (your examples above are strings, so your question is not clear on this), then you need to use jsviews.js, not jsrender.js, and the link() method, rather than the render method (http://www.jsviews.com/#jsv-quickstart). Now you have access to the elements so you can do these variants too:

```
<div id="e" data-link="data-key{:~myOb}"></div>
<div id="f" data-link="{setdata 'myKey' ~myOb}"></div>
```

using

```
jQuery.views.tags({
  setdata: function(key, value) {
    $(this.linkCtx.elem).data(key, value);
  }
});
```

and

```
tmpl.link("#result", myData, {myOb: {foo: "fooValue"}});
console.log($("#e").data('myKey').foo
  + " " + $("#f").data('myKey').foo); //fooValue fooValue
```

Comment: But set data using html like data-[variable]=value will exposed in html and also set data as JSONObject or Array is not possible in your example.

Comment: Well yes, JsRender renders as a string, so it can only set data via that HTML markup string. Otherwise you should use JsViews, and then you can access the elements directly, not via HTML markup. See my updated reply.